# Why do I get general failure when I try to write the authentication key to the RPMB partition using mmc-utils

Tags: linux, authentication, embedded-linux, mmc

When I try to write the authentication key to the device using

```
mmc rpmb write-key /dev/mmcblk0rpmb /opt/data/keyfile.txt
```

or

```
echo -n AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHH | mmc rpmb write-key /dev/mmcblk0rpmb -
```

I get the following error message

```
RPMB operation failed, retcode 0x0001
```

Do you know that the reason could be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this problem?
In *Embedded Multi-Media Card (e•MMC) Electrical Standard (5.1)*

> 6.6.22.4.1 Programming of the Authentication Key
> The Authentication Key is programmed with the Write Multiple Block command, CMD25. Prior to the command CMD25 the block count is set to 1 by CMD23, with argument bit [31] set as 1 to indicate Reliable Write type of programming. If block count has not been set to 1 and/or argument bit [31] has not been set to 1 then the subsequent Write Multiple Block command must fail and General Failure shall be indicated.
> Does it help?

Comment: If the RPMB Key has been programmed, this error message will be returned too.